# Generating Unique Codes Per Email In Eloqua

Tags: email, unique, eloqua

I need to send an email to all of my contacts, within that email is going to be a coupon for $XXX off their future purchase. In MailChimp this would be easy, but I cannot find any information in the Eloqua support forums or via Google on how to do this. For each email a unique code needs to be generated and attached automatically to that coupon button for them to access.

I've never used Eloqua before and just picked up a client who insists it be what we use. I more accustomed to using MailChimp or Emma. Just a little background.

Is there a custom content area I'm missing or is this not a feature available through Eloqua?